# WebStorm report error on Less "property variables"

Tags: less, webstorm

How do I enable the [Less properties as variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties-as-variables-new-) feature in WebStorm?

When I try to use the properties as variables in Less WebStorm reports it as an error but my code compiles without any error.
Even when I do something as simple as this:

```
body {
  color: black;
  button {
    border-color: $color;
  }
}
```

I searched on web but it seems like I'm the only one to have this issue. I hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently supported: it's a brand new functionality (since Less v3) that is not yet implemented in WebStorm.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31443 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.